# How to delete all data > 70 characters in a column

Tags: sql

Can you help me to delete all characters > 70 in a "Title" column in `dbo.tabs` with a SQL script?

Comment: How about, _at least_,  telling us which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4):

```
update dbo.Tabs 
set Title = substring(Title,1,70);
```

Comment: thank you chetan! I have correct a little error "substrig = substring" and works perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome. corrected the spelling mistake.

Comment: If this is working, why don't you accept it as the right answer?